# How do I change Portal 2 subtitle language?

Tags: portal-2

I'm a native English speaker (born in US to Swedish parents) and I run a Swedish YouTube channel.

Would it be possible to set Portal 2 CC to Swedish? I've set the language in Steam to Swedish (Right-Click on Portal 2 > Properties > Language > Swedish (Sweden)) but that only changed the interface language.

I've tried using dev console by typing "cc_lang swedish", but it says something along the lines of "resource/subtitles_swedish.txt is missing, using resource/subtitles_english.txt instead" even though I checked the folder, and the file is there, I opened it and everything seems to work, therefore the file isn't corrupted.

I tried using "Verify Game Cache Integrity" and that passes fine too.

Screenshot of "resource" folder that shows the file exists:

[image: Screenshot showing the existence of the swedish subtitles file]

Comment: Have you tried doing cc_lang swedish in the steam launch options rather than the dev console?

Comment: Yeah, I have, it says the same thing in the console when the game starts up.

Comment: The only way to do this is by changing the language that you load up steam with.

Comment: Hm, `cc_lang swedish` works for me. What happens if you just type `cc_lang`? || Does the same problem happen if you change from *Subtitles Only* to *Full Captions*? || Have you tried right-clicking *Portal 2* in your library, going to *Properties*, then under the *Language* tab selecting *Svenska (Swedish)*?

Comment: Deleting the entire game from the folder (manually, not from Steam) seems to have fixed the issue. I reinstalled the game afterwards **AND** it worked by setting game language to Swedish in Preferences and console (Why? I don't know, don't ask).

Answer (score 1):

Portal 2 dosent support swedish subtitles
http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/
On the portal 2 Languages tab it says:

--------------| Interface  |  Full audio |  subtitles |

Swedish:   ____✓________X________X

Which means Swedish supports only the interface...
Maybe there is a Swedish mod!

Comment: Well, it does work. I managed to get it to work. I don't know what the problem was, but it's all okay now.
EDIT: I checked the language tab, it says that it doesn't support subtitles for any language, I'm sure that's just a mistake because English and Swedish subtitles work.